# Java Compress no return?

Tags: java, string

what my code is supposed to be doing is converting input strings and outputing the compressed versions

Ex. Input: "qqqwww" Output: "3q3w".

But my code returns nothing.

P.S. IO is just an input system.

```
public class Compress {
    public static String compress(String original){
        String s = "";

        char s1 = original.charAt(0);
        int count = 1;

        for(int i = 0; i < original.length(); i++){
            char c = original.charAt(i);

            if(c == s1){
                count++;
            }
            else{
                s = s + count + s1; //i think the problem is here right???
                count = 1;
            }
            s1 = c;
        }
        return s;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String s = IO.readString();

        String y = compress(s); 

        System.out.println(y);


    }

}
```

Comment: You should step through the code with a debugger. Or by hand

Comment: Well I see an input of "qqqwww" printing output of "4q"...

Comment: When I run your code, I get "4q".

Comment: You're counting element 0 twice, and don't take active spans into account after exiting the loop.

Comment: I never said i was done but how are you guys getting returns because when i run it nothing happens???

Comment: Cyrstal ball says: Whatever IO is, it doesn't work like you think it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your could should look like this :

```
String returnString="";
    for (int index = 0; index < original.length();) {
        char currentChar = original.charAt(index);
        int counter=1;
        while(++index < original.length() && currentChar==original.charAt(index)) {
            counter++;
        }
        returnString=returnString+counter+currentChar;
    }
    return returnString;
}
```

Here we loop thought the string (outer for loop) and check if the adjacent values are same the we keep adding them. (inner while loop)

Comment: The code is a bit off. if i type "qwwwwwwwwweeeeerrtyyyyyqqqqwEErTTT" the result is 2q9w5e2r6y4q3E3T it doesnt desplay the one t or the one r.

Comment: edit all you needed to do was add + 1 at the 5th line thanks friend!

Comment: It worked fine for me 1q9w5e2r1t5y4q1w2E1r3T make sure that you don't introduce some side effects.

Comment: i see you dont have a index++ in the for loop is that intentional?

Comment: Yes ! its in the inner loop while condition.